# PS Query - multiple values within a single prompt

Tags: prompt, peoplesoft

In PeopleSoft Query, I want to allow users to choose multiple values within a single prompt. I work at a higher education institution, so I'll give a real time example.  In the Faculty of Science (the field is GRP), there are 8 departments - Biology, Chemistry, Computer Science, etc.(this field is an ORG) .  In the prompt for ORG, I want the user, within that single prompt, to choose multiple ORG values. So far, the only solution I have come across is to create multiple prompts and allow the user to choose each ORG separately.  Is this even possible?  I did research earlier, and someone 7 years ago posted a solution, but later on someone else indicated that this only works for earlier tools versions.  I tried to run the solution and it failed (as predicted).

Has anyone figured out a way to do it in PS Query?  The only other recommendation that I have received is to write the report in BI Publisher.

Comment: I don't know of any way to allow multiple values to be selected for a single field.  You could put eight check boxes on your query prompts (one for each department) and then have your query do something like `SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE (CHECKBOX_1 = 'Y' AND ORG = 'BIO') OR (CHECKBOX_2 = 'Y' AND ORG = 'CHEM')...`

Comment: Thanks. I was afraid that the only way was to have multiple selection boxes/prompts to accomplish this, but was hoping that someone might have an answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. In PS 9.2, create multiple prompts for the same field (:1, :2,..., :N).
2. Give them unique names in the Heading Text field (Org1, Org2,..., OrgN).
3. Add Criteria and in Expression1 select the Field Name (Org).
4. Select Condition Type 'in list' (Expression Type defaults to 'In List').
5. For Expression2 (Edit List), click the magnifying glass to add members.
6. On the Edit List page, click the Add Prompt link and select prompt :1 (repeat for prompts :2 through :N).
7. Click OK and save your changes.